# MoSync linking with external library

Tags: c++, ios

I just discovered the [MoSync SDK](http://www.mosync.com/) and I considered it as a very good option for C++ programmers for producing iOS & Android applications using the same source code. the MAUI API is very easy to learn for C++ programmer.
I tested a provided example on iPhone simulator and it works pretty well. But when looked to the xcodeproject files a found a C++ source file which looks like an assembler code. I searched for information about the compilation process and It seems the original c++ code is translated to IL language and the IL language is converted to a C++ code.

Does any one have any idea regarding the performance issue of this process. is the generated code is efficient ?

I thought of making a simple iOS apple with some UIs that call my C++ code in a static library. So i made a static library (libmylib.a) which exports one function :

```
extern "C" double tst_function(double x)
{
    return sin(x)+2.5;
}
```

Then I called `tst_function` from inside the MoSync HelloNativeUI example and added libmylib.a to the linker flags in the MoSync IDE. But I got an error in the compile process:

```
>>pipe-tool libmylib.a -appcode=KOOU -stabs=stabs.tab .....
 
failed to load '-appcode=KOOU'
```

I tried also to add libmylib.a to the additional libraries just after mastdD.lib, MAUtilD.lib, NativeUI.lib , but I got this error message :

So how to tell the MoSync IDE about calling external function located in static libraries ?

```
pipe-tool Copyright 2007-2009 Mobile Sorcery AB
pass 1. 97 known symbols.
/Users/mosyncbuilder/slave/buildScripts/temp_j4DF/source/libs/NativeUI/ActivityIndicator.cpp:58: Error: Illegal instruction '!<arch>',
```

So how to tell the IDE MoSync about calling functions from external static libraries ?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

Pipe-tool will only accept MoSync IL, but you tried to feed it ARM code. That's not going to work.

However, there may be a possible workaround. You could create a stub library, compile it with your program, then remove it from the generated c++ code and replace it with the proper version.

Comment: Thank you for the idea of replacing the stub library. But are u sur that it will work ? The ARM code generated by mosync for the function 'double tst_func( double x) ' will be ' int tst_func(int i0, int i1) ' . Does the ARM code generated by Xcode is identical to the mosync code ?